# Android clickable layer

Tags: android, button, layer, clickable

I have set linearlayer to become clickable and want it to act like a button and start a new activity. However i got error. Here are part of the .xml

```
            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llproduct1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="vertical" android:clickable="true">
            <ImageView .... />
            <TextView .... />
            </LinearLayout>
```

This is the .java
    Button bProduct1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.llproduct1);
        bProduct1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.testing.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION"));
        }
```

What went wrong?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button bProduct1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.llproduct1);
```

you cannot cast your LinearLayout to a button. But you can do:

```
 LinearLayout bProduct1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llproduct1); 
 bProduct1.setOnClickListener(...)
```

[see this for reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)

Comment: Thanks!! but i think i got one more error, still have error. 

<activity android:name=".ProductDescription"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.testing.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong class casting in "bProduct1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.llproduct1); "

'llproduct1' is LinearLayout!! not a Button.
therefore the java code cause ClassCastException.

onClick method is declared in View class.
and both of LinearLayout and Button are inheriting View class.

so why don't you fix the code below.

```
View bProduct1 = findViewById(R.id.llproduct1);
bProduct1.setOnClickListener(......);
```

Comment: Thanks!! but i think i got one more error, still have error. <activity android:name=".ProductDescription" android:label="@string/app_name"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.testing.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> </intent-filter> </activity>